# zsh: How to populate completion candidates with specific order

Tags: zsh

I would like to populate completion candidates with the exact order specified in the function. From what I understand, `-o nosort` should do the trick, but it is not working as expected. I must be missing something very basic. What's that?

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -u
compdef _foo foo
_foo() {
  compadd -o nosort -- ccc aaa bbb
}
```

```
% foo <Tab>
aaa  bbb  ccc
# Want: ccc aaa bbb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why that is needed but adding a *group name* via `-J the-group-name` or `-V the-group-name` (which is short for `-J the-group-name -o nosort`) works. So:

```
compadd -V 'foo operands' -- ccc aaa bbb
```

I never really spent the effort to understand how the completion system works in details. When trying to define some custom completers, I usually look at the ones supplied by zsh as examples. Here `grep -rw -- nosort $fpath` reveals a few completers using it. Doing `functions -t one-of-those-completers` enables tracing for that completer and shows how compadd is being invoked for those.